# How do I change default shutter sound in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-camera

Is there any way to replace the camera shutter sound in Android? I'd like to replace the shutter sound, the sound the camera makes when snapping a photo, with something else in code.

I used this code to silence the phone right before taking the picture, and unsilencing it right after:

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

I'd prefer to replace the sound with another `.mp3` or `.ogg` that can be set dynamically by the user.

I understand if you have a rooted phone, you can replace the file. This is not a solution for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound is played from the cameraservice in the native layer of any device (libcameraservice.so). And hence any modifications in the played out sound has to be done here.

On hindsight:

The sound playing part in the above library is a result of a shutter callback from device camera. This checks for the volume index and hence does not playout any sound when you set the device to mute. When the event is later transferred to the app layer your implementation of Camera.ShutterCallback (refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback) is called and hence here can unmute the audio manager and playback your audio file using the Android audio playback class like audio track.

Comment: So the solution is to set the device to mute on ShutterCallback and unmute e in other callback fucntion and then play the other sound?

Comment: Set the device to mute before calling the takePicture call and unmute in the OnShutterCallback. This will mute the internal sound but you can plaback yours after the unmute.

Comment: I did this in my app before call camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,jpegCallback); mute device AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM. And Unmute in shutter callback method and play my sound file from Raw folder but Some time it playing system file as well as my file. How to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean sometimes? Do you get to hear only your capture tine any time?

Comment: I've seen this behaviour with the start/stop sounds for MediaRecorder. My suspicion is that the unmuting happens too early, i.e. the stream is unmuted before the sound is played (presumably due to queuing). The workaround I put in place was to execute the unmute call after a 0.5s delay (which did the trick on my Nexus 4). Not ideal but it works. Note that this would account for the 'sometimes' that @Deepak mentions since sometimes the muting would happen before the sound is played and sometimes afterwards (I'm guessing).