# Check if the camera shutter sound is on or off in the settings Android

Tags: android, camera, shutter

I'm using a custom camera application , i want the camera to enable the shutter sound if it was on on the device and turn it off otherwise , so is there a default method which will check that , or can i get the settings information of the camera to find that .

I tried this code , but it sounds that is check on the device sound.

```
    AudioManager audioService = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (audioService.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
Camera.getCameraInfo(id, info);
if (info.canDisableShutterSound) {
    mCamera.enableShutterSound(false)
}
```

[How to mute camera shutter sound on android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383083/how-to-mute-camera-shutter-sound-on-android-phone)

Comment: thank you but how can i get the id of the camera , and this method will return if i can turn it on or off ,, but how to know if it is on or off?